# HTML and CSS horizontal webpage menu with Home icon

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a simple horizontal menu with a dropdown, but I want to add a home icon to the left, inline with the other text menu items...stumped here. Can anyone help?

Like this:

[image]

```css
.btn {
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav">

  <a class="active" font="bold" href="../secure/index.html">HTML</a>    
  <a class="active" font="bold" href="../index.html">CSS</a>
  <a class="active" font="bold" href="../index.html">CSS</a>
</div>
```

Update: There is a white space about the horizontal menu, and I cannot figure out what it is.
[image]

Comment: Read the docs. : https://fontawesome.com/v4/icon/home

Comment: wrap the `i` element of the icon inside an `a` element with the page's href, button is not needed. never use button for navigation.

Comment: use the semantic tags such as `nav`. Than simply use flexbox for a perfect alignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap anchor tag around the icon

```css
nav {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

nav a {

  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav>
  <a href="whereYouWouldLikeItToLinkTo"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="active" font="bold" href="../secure/index.html">HTML</a>    
  <a class="active" font="bold" href="../index.html">CSS</a>
  <a class="active" font="bold" href="../index.html">CSS</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you all, it works!! Odd thing I have noticed, there is a space above my horizontal menu...anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

To include the home icon you need to add `<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>`. Then simply apply `display: flex` on the container. To space them apart youc an use the `gap`property. To vertical center them use `align-items: cenetr`

```css
nav {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav>
  <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <a class="active" font="bold" href="../secure/index.html">HTML</a>    
  <a class="active" font="bold" href="../index.html">CSS</a>
  <a class="active" font="bold" href="../index.html">CSS</a>
</nav>
```